# Return Object from soap method in protractor

Tags: soap, protractor, node-modules, node-soap

I am using "soap" for testing my application wsdls in protractor.
this is the code I am using 
[image]

I want 'servicechitest' function to return "results" object(highlighted in the screenshot). It prints expected output to the console.
Not sure where can I place return statement to get results object.

Comment: Don't post the code as a screenshot. try to post it as a text content, So it will be easy for others to provide detailed answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a promise to get the value from an asynchronous method. you can use `q` module from npm to implement promise.

to install `q`, run the below command in terminal,

```
npm install q
```

once `q` is downloaded, Use it in your application like below,

```
var q= require('q');

servicehitest : function () {
    var url ="someurl";
    var args= [];
    var defered = q.defer();
    soap.creatClient(url,creatClient);
    function  clientCreate(err,client) {
        if(err){
            console.log("in error block");
            console.log(client.describe());
        }
        client.getInstrument(args,instrument);
        function instrument(err,result){
            if(err){
                defered.reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log(result);
                defered.resolve(result);
            }
        }
    }
    return defered.promise;
}
```

To get the result from `servicehitest` method, use the below code.

```
servicehitest().then(function(result){
  //this method will be called when the result is obtained from getInstrument() method.
  console.log("Successfully got result:"+result);
},
function(error){
  //error callback method will be called if there is any error from getInstrument() method.
console.log("Some error occured:"+error);
})
```

Comment: Thanks dude! It worked.
I will add code in text format henceforth.